# Specify filename in function: df.to_json

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I simply want to save my dataframe df as JSON-file on my disk. The filename should exist of a static name (btDaten) and the current systemtime.

Is there any way to this in an easy way? Should like something like this then...

`df.to_json(r'C:\Users\Max\Dropbox\Seminararbeit\Prototyp\btDaten-17_11_2020-14:56')`

TY & BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os` to join paths and `datetime`to get the current datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

folder = r"C:\Users\Max\Dropbox\Seminararbeit\Prototyp"
filename = "btDaten"
sys_dtime = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y-%H%M")

filepath = os.path.join(folder, f"{filename}{sys_dtime}.json")

df.to_json(filepath)
```

Comment: Tried it, but now the file gets saved without any extension. In addition, the file isn't in JSON, it's just empty.  Tried something like `filename ="test"+datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y-%H:%M")+".json" ` but that didn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the problem was the ":" in the filename that produces empty output (also forgot the filetype). I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but unfortunately it's still not working. Guess there is a problem between the time format and the ".json" extension as string. When taking of the time string, just using `filename="test.json"` it's working..

Comment: Well the datetime format should be something like "19_11_2020-1311". So nothing fancy. Could you print an anonymous `filepath` before saving to json, please?

Comment: Nevermind dude, you were completely right. Forgot to change `"%H:%M`. Now it's working fine, thank you alot!

Comment: Glad I could help (: